# Find n characters after a specific string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, parsing, full-text-indexing

I have a webpage's source. It's just a ton of random numbers and letters and function names, saved as a string in python3. I want to find the text that says `\"followerCount\":` in the source code of this string, but I also want to find a little bit of the text that follows it (*n* characters). This would hopefully have the piece of text I'm looking for. Can I search for a specific part of a string and **the *n* characters that follow it** in python3?

Comment: Show us the string, the expected result and what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.find()` to get the position:

```
html = "... lots of html source ..."
position = html.find('"followerCount":')
```

Then use string slicing to extract that part of the string:

```
n = 50 # or however many characters you want
print(html[position:position+n])
```

Comment: Seems like you need to take the length of the searched-for text into account since find will find the beginning of that string.

Comment: Glad to hear it @vladusatii! Maybe I misunderstood your questions, but when I used this with `n=3` I got `"fo` instead of the three characters after the string.

Answer (score 0):

A standard way of looking for text based on a pattern is a regex. For example here you can ask for any three characters following "followerCount:"

```
import re

s = 'a bunch of randoms_characters/"followerCount":123_more_junk'

match = re.search(r'(?<="followerCount":).{3}', s)
if match:
    print(match.group(0))
    #prints '123'
```

Alternatively you can make a regex without the lookbehind and capture the three characters in a group:

```
import re

s = 'a bunch of randoms_characters/"followerCount":123_more_junk'

match = re.search(r'"followerCount":(.{3})', s)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
    #prints '123'
```